Issue Compiling Tesseract OCR on AWS SageMaker: GCC Version and Filesystem Error
I’m trying to compile the latest version of Tesseract OCR on AWS SageMaker (Amazon Linux 2), so I can use PyMupdf OCR functions. After successfully installing Leptonica 1.85.0 from source, I attempted to compile Tesseract. During the make process, I encountered the following error:
``
src/api/baseapi.cpp:67:10: fatal error: filesystem: no such file or directory
#include <filesystem> // for std::filesystem
``

I am using GCC 7.3.1 (the default version on AWS) and received errors related to the  header. I also tried exporting the correct paths for Leptonica using PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig, but the issue persists.
I attempted to install libstdc++-devel and use GCC from /usr/local/bin, but it didn’t resolve the issue. Is this a compatibility problem with the version of GCC, or is there a missing dependency? What would be the best way to proceed in this SageMaker environment?
Any advice on how to troubleshoot this would be greatly appreciated!

You use an old compiler (c++17 is required for building Tesseract).

Thanks. I solved it by updating GCC to the latest version.
